# NSAttributed string display quotation with vertical line

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I want to display quotations from html tag  as vertical line and text right of it. How I can do this with attributed string?
Here is what i want

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be in an attributed string? Could it be a single pixel width view to the left of a label?

Comment: @AshleyMills i receiving HTML from server, and quote may be in HTML multiple times, so I have to display all quotes, and other text can be present in html

Comment: There is nothing done in `NSAttributedString` to do so. If the NSAttributedString initialization from HTML doesn't do it, then you can't. You'll have to customize your rendering, playing maybe with CoreText, NSTextLayout, etc. It's not easy.

Comment: Can you give a snippet of HTML containing quoted text?

Comment: @Larme maybe you have some examples? I'm totally noob:)

Comment: @AshleyMills sure, here is
<blockquote><blockquote><blockquote>text</blockquote></blockquote><br /><blockquote>some</blockquote></blockquote>

Comment: It's quite complex, not that much documented. I wouldn't recommend it for a debutant. Maybe there are some third party library that do it already.

Comment: @Larme I tried to find, but without luck for quotes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=blockquote+nsattributedstring

Comment: @Larme is that good idea to use UIWebView in TableView cell for displaying html content?

Comment: @AshleyMills tried this way already, don't find anything(

Comment: I would suggest parse html/xml from the website with this [library](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna) and then populate your own data structure. Set up flags or something to determine whether should you draw a line and then use CoreGraphics or just UIView (simpler) inside CollectionViewCell

Comment: @DenisLitvin how can i draw this line inside text? I can have multiple quotes in different places of text

Comment: You don't have to draw this inside text. In fact, you can't. Decouple your text lines and treat them as different objects. Once you get your strings, you can place them and draw lines wherever you want. The easier approach is to use UILabel and UITextView, for more advanced and efficient  check out CoreText

Comment: @DenisLitvin when I say draw in text, I mean in label or in textview, so if i decople my strings, how can I draw the text with lines in textview?